# IE IE11 angularjs controller won't load - $controller:ctrlreg error

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-11

I know this isn't the right way to document this, but I feel the "question" is important enough that an answer should be readily searchable.

I have an angularjs controller that loads perfectly in chrome and firefox, but not in IE(11). Long story short, chrome supports [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `()=>{}` and internet explorer does not.

A controller, or one of the dependencies of that controller that are written with arrow expressions will not even load in IE, arrow expressions are seen as syntax errors.

The fix is, where your code has arrow expressions `() =>`, 
change them to `function()`, and you're golden.

Comment: So what's the question here? Usually to fix that issue you use pollyfill

Comment: Use a build system (angular-cli, webpack, gulp, ...) and transpile the code with Babel. Besides, Angular (v2+) and AngularJS (v1.x) are not the same. Can you make clear what framework you are using?

Comment: To fix that issue you can't use a polyfill, it's a syntax error issue. What is being documented here is an issue where the controller loads and executes perfectly in one browser, but won't even load in another (IE11).

Comment: I think the point is being missed here. The point is, that because of the lack of support for arrow functions, it is possible to write a controller that loads and runs perfectly in chrome and firefox but not in IE11. People experiencing this ctrlreg error in angular will be searching about errors related to IE11, since like me they will not know that lack of support for arrow functions is the real issue. This is important and needs to be documented.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to mention Babel not pollyfills. What Guido Flohr mention. Also this is not the place for documentation.

Comment: You can use babel.js to convert your ES6 code to ES5 code which will work in IE without any issue.